# events in fullcalendar/VUE application not updating

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fullcalendar

Inside of my **cal.vue** component I have a `fullcalendar` component. Within **cal.vue** I have a method called submit. Inside of submit I make a (successful) reference to the `fullcalendar` component with `this.$refs.calendar`. However when I do `this.$refs.calendar.$emit('refetchEvents');` in my submit function the events are not fetched (my events are not updated on my calendar). Why are my events not being updated upon submit and how can I update them?

Here is the relevant code:

```
<template>
   <div id="calendar"  :navL="navLinks" :event-sources="eventSources" @event-selected="eventSelected" @event-created="eventCreated" :config="config" >
      <button    class="btn btn-secondary" v-on:click="submit()">
         Submit
      </button>
      <full-calendar id="target" ref="calendar" :event-sources="eventSources" @event-selected="eventSelected" @day-click="click"@event-created="eventCreated" :config="config"></full-calendar>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
   const self = this;
   export default {
      name: 'calendar',
      data() {
         return {
            eventSources: [
               {
                  url: 'http://localhost:3000/getAppointments',
                  type: 'GET',
                  data: {
                     id: this.$store.getters.user
                  },
                  error: function() {
                     alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
                  },
               }
            ],  
         };
      },

      methods: {
         submit: function() {
            console.log(this.$refs.calendar); //prints fullcalendar VUE component
            this.$refs.calendar.$emit('refetchEvents'); //nothing appears to happen here
         },
      },
   }
</script>
```

Comment: What is `full-calendar`? A Vue component wrapping a jQuery plugin? Does it still use jQuery?

Comment: full-calendar is a VUE component wrapping the jQuery plugin fullcalendar. I believe it uses jQuery

Comment: Do you have a link? There are at least two Vue wrappers.

Comment: calendar.vue is where the above code is located

Comment: If the VUE code looks ok it could be a problem with the vue-fullcalendar wrapper I am using. I'll post an issue to them and see what they say

Comment: I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-full-calendar#listens-on),

```
this.$refs.calendar.$emit('refetchEvents')
```

should be

```
this.$refs.calendar.$emit('refetch-events')
```

Comment: thanks Bert I tried that but it does not seem to work

Comment: @matt can you set up an example that shows the issue? I cant run your code.

Comment: Actually Bert its gonna be pretty hard to set up cause I got to configure a db as well

Comment: @Matt yup, this is why, if you can isolate the issue, we can work on it.

Comment: I dont know if I can create a fullworking example right now but thanks for your help so far. It's probably a problem with the wrapper I'll wait till they respond and post what the result is here

Comment: @matt sorry we couldn't get further. BTW are you working with someone else on this? I think RandyMoss has posted questions on the same repo.

Answer (score 0):

If using the vanilla FullCalendar via npm packages: "@fullcalendar/core", "@fullcalendar/daygrid", "@fullcalendar/timegrid", "@fullcalendar/vue"

```
html: <full-calendar ref="fullCalendar" :events="events" />
inside a method to update an event:
        let calendar = this.$refs.fullCalendar.getApi()
        const updatedEvent = calendar.getEventById(eventId)
        updatedEvent.setProp('title', 'New Title')
        updatedEvent.setProp('backgroundColor', 'yellow')
        updatedEvent.setProp('borderColor', 'yellow')
        updatedEvent.setProp('textColor', 'black')
```

The above will rerender the fullCalendar event but will not change your this.events array. There may be something that's a bit more all inclusive for ALL events in one shot otherwise you'd have to do:

```
this.events.forEach(event => {
  ...similar code the above
})
```